# How to translate a model label in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-i18n

I could translate Django Admin except a model label because I don't know how to translate a model label in Django Admin.

So, how can I translate a model label in Django Admin?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Look at the [`Meta` options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`, both of which are translatable.

Comment: but this will only change the name in home page,but when u click on the link(class) the upper header will display the class name which u mention before.

verbose_name will only change the title in home page

Comment: In Django 1.11 this is indeed the correct answer. The verbose_name appears on the admin home page and on every sub-page.

Answer (score 21):

You should use the **ugettext_lazy** util in the Meta of all your models

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Book(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("My Book")
        verbose_name_plural = _("My Books")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) and set it to [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) and [verbose_name_plural](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural) to translate a model label in Django Admin as shown below. *You can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418) explaining how to translate in Django in detail:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Person(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("person") # Here
        verbose_name_plural = _("persons") # Here
```

Answer (score 0):

also you can override admin.ModelAdmin to customize model name in admin only, without changing Model meta

```
def __init__(self, model: type, admin_site: AdminSite) -> None:
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)
        self.opts.verbose_name = 'your custom model name'
        self.opts.verbose_name_plural = 'your custom title plural'
```