# Verbose name for admin model Class in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is it possible to create a verbose name for the actual Class model?

```
class User(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = 'first name')
```

So in the admin panel it will be referenced by its verbose name and not `'user'` ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
class User(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = 'first name')

    class Meta:
         verbose_name = "users"
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#meta-options

Comment: and they are translatable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462905/is-it-possible-to-change-the-model-name-in-the-django-admin-site

Answer (score 18):

**verbose_name** and **verbose_name_plural** both the properties of **Meta** class are very important to modify the default behaviour of Django to display the name of our models on **Admin interface**.

You can change the display of your **model names** using on **Admin Interface** using **verbose_name** and **verbose_name_plural** properties and **model fields names** using keyword argument **verbose_name**.

Please find the below **2** examples.

**Country** model:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, help_text="Your country", verbose_name="name")
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Country {str(self.id)} - {self.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Country"
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
```

If you will not specify **verbose_name_plural** then Django will take it as **Countrys** which does not look good as we want it as **Countries**.

This better fits in the following type of **Model**.

**Gender** model:

```
class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, help_text="Gender", verbose_name = "name")
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Gender {str(self.id)} - {self.name}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Gender"
```

Comment: *title = models.CharField(max_length=25 ,verbose_name=_("Quiz Title"))* what it will do in this case and where am I going to use it.

Answer (score 9):

You could add a "verbose_name_plural" to the "Meta" class too.

Comment: Works for Django 3

Answer (score 6):

To alter admin model without polluting the model itself, you can utilize a proxy admin model, like this:

```
# admin.py
from . import models

class Users(models.User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class UsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...


admin.site.register(Users, UsersAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ConfigAbility._meta.verbose_name = 'config ability'

> ConfigAbility._meta.verbose_name_plural = 'config ability'

I did explore this, but don't know whether it's the thing you need. I put those codes in class ConfigAbilityAdmin in Admin.py. Then, the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW23C.png)

With this approach, you don't need to config Meta method in model class, especially when model class's code is generated from inspectdb...