# Change model class name in Django admin interface

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Verbose name for admin model Class in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959462/verbose-name-for-admin-model-class-in-django)

I had a model with a class like:

```
class Anh_chi_tiet(models.Model):
    du_an       = models.ForeignKey(Du_an)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    url         = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    url_detail  = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

When I go to admin interface, my Anh_chi_tiet class has a label: Anh_chi_tiets (added s suffix)
But I want to change my class label to "My image"

How can I do that?

Comment: **verbose_name** is sufficient and don't  use  **verbose_name_plural**.

Comment: It is required if you want **Country** and **Countries** as by default django adds **s** at the end of value of **verbose_name**. So if you will not use **verbose_name_plural** then you will see displayed model name as **Countrys**.

Comment: If you want to change the name in plural you can use `verbose_name_plural = "stories"` so you don't get `storys`  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Via inner `Meta` class, as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#verbose-name):

```
class Anh_chi_tiet(models.Model):
    # ... fields ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'My image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'My images'
```

Comment: And if you only want to change this in the admin, not everywhere it's used?

Comment: No answer on how to do this in the admin...

Comment: You should add the class Meta on the model not on the model admin!

Comment: Unfortunatelly changing only the name in the admin won't happens since it defined as `'name': capfirst(model._meta.verbose_name_plural),` (Django 3.1)

Comment: If you only want to change this in the admin you can use a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). See [this answer in the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65434272/5286674).