# Change the text of a sidemenu item on django-admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a couple of items (namely authentication and user_central) on the side menu of my django-admin interface which are shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I want to change their text. How can I do that? I know a litle bit about overriding the template, but which blocks to override for these two menu items?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change model class name in Django admin interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368937/change-model-class-name-in-django-admin-interface)

Comment: @dabadaba I don't think so. The post you have mentioned tells how to change the text of subentries, in my case these subentries come under 'user_central'. But I want to change the text of parent menu item, which is 'user_central' itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you give a Django app a verbose name for use throughout the admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately, you don't have to tweak any template to achieve this!

In your apps, go to apps.py and add or change the AppConfig's `verbose_name`.

Example:

```
class UserCentralConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'user_central'
      verbose_name = 'Users'
```

Don't forget to reference this config class in you settings.py, like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'user_central.apps.UserCentralConfig',
  ...
]
```

Comment: It gave me this error `ImportError: No module named UserCentralConfigdjango.contrib`

Comment: I figured it out. You were partly correct. Instead of registering it with the `INSTALLED_APPS`, we need to put it in the __init__.py file of the app, like so: `default_app_config = 'YourApp.apps.YourAppConfig'
`.
I'm marking your answer as 'accepted' since it led me to the solution. Thanks

Comment: BTW, this is fine about one of the menu items. What about the `Authentication` menu item which is not a model and comes out of the box with django-admin? Any idea?

Comment: `default_app_config` Is not required in any django >= 1.7, so schwobaseggl were right!

Comment: Actually, for django >= 1.7, it IS required. For lower versions, it isn't.

Comment: To customize the `Authentication` verbose_name, I've had good result by overloading `AuthConfig` from `django.contrib.auth.apps`. Basically this:
`class CustomAuthConfig(AuthConfig):
    verbose_name = 'Custom Name'`
So you'll need to make a new app and reference this config in the `__init__.py` just like you did above. And you should use something like `custom_auth.apps.CustomAuthConfig` instead of `django.contrib.auth`.

Comment: No, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#configuring-applications):
`default_app_config allows applications that predate Django 1.7 such as django.contrib.admin to opt-in to AppConfig features without requiring users to update their INSTALLED_APPS.

New applications should avoid default_app_config. Instead they should require the dotted path to the appropriate AppConfig subclass to be configured explicitly in INSTALLED_APPS.`

Comment: yeah, docs say that. But I am using django 1.8 and I had to use `default_app_config` since `INSTALLED_APPS` didn't work.

Comment: and that `custom_auth` method is again giving the import error I mentioned earlier. It says `ImportError: No module named CustomAuthConfigdjango.contrib` when I put it in the `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Also, is it possible to override the default logo as well?