# How to change Users name tag in Admin Django

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm working with Django, and I use my own customized User Class, just like this:

```
class Company(User):
    objects = UserManager()
```

All works as expected, but in the admin, it shows the name of the class as User, not Company, as shown in this image below:

[image: Class Company in admin]

It's just the tag, all works correctly, but I wanted to know if there's a way to change the tag to Company, not Users.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `verbose_name` attribute in django models. `verbose_name_plural` can be used to define any plural attribute

```
class Company(User):
    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Company"
        verbose_name_plural = "Companies"
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in this topic: [Verbose name for admin model Class in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959462/verbose-name-for-admin-model-class-in-django)

You need to use a subclass Meta and set its verbose_name attribute:

```
class Company(User):
    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Company"
```