# Is there a way to give tables a human readable name in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In django admin, I realize that my table names are rather ugly and not user friendly. Is there a way that I can add some type of alternative name that would appear in the admin instead of the real name?

Something like ulgy_table_name -- alt name = Better looking name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verbose name for admin model Class in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959462/verbose-name-for-admin-model-class-in-django)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you give a Django app a verbose name for use throughout the admin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612372/can-you-give-a-django-app-a-verbose-name-for-use-throughout-the-admin)

Comment: Isnt verbose name just for fields? I want something like that for the table name

Answer (score 3):

```
class User(models.Model):
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name = 'Better looking name')
```

**Edited :** If you wan to change the table name in admin try below

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    pass
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'my_app_name'
```

Note :

> You need to have an app in INSTALLED_APPS that matches your app_label or your tables won't get created.

Comment: isnt this just for the field though? I want that but for a table name

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to change the table names (by changing the model names) if you don't want to. You can change define it either on the Model itself or on the `ModelAdmin` in your `admin.py`. Just override the `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural` in their `Meta` options

```
class ... (...):
   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'readable'
       verbose_name_plural = 'readables'
```

etc.

Comment: Is it possible to display the custom table name(i.e=> db_table) in admin page instead of using the class name which is declared in models.py.

Comment: you'd have to find a way to set the `verbose_name` to  `db_table`'s value