# How do you change the displayed model name in the admin site of Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How do you change the displayed model name in the admin site of Django? Currently admin site just add an 's' after the model name.

Comment: the link answer does not answer the question, because  that will only change the name in home page,but when u click on the link(class) the upper header will

Comment: set `verbose_name_plural` for your model will remove the  's' after the model name.

Comment: You should use the `verbose_name_plural` in the Meta of your model.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462905/is-it-possible-to-change-the-model-name-in-the-django-admin-site/45463026#45463026) here for a complete example